# How Do I Disable All Buttons After Every Individual Button Is Clicked Once?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I'm having trouble trying to disable both the powerButton and the squareRootButton in the code. Any ideas what to do?

I've tried creating a counter to keep track of the times the buttons were clicked, but at the end of the method those variables are re-initialized everytime the method starts again. I can't create any more instance data variables by homework instructions and I would have if it was allowed.

```
//Forgot to mention that this is JavaFx.

private void handleButtons (ActionEvent event) {

        try {
            double numberFieldInput = Double.parseDouble(numberField.getText());
            double powerFieldInput = Double.parseDouble(powerField.getText());

            if(event.getSource() == powerButton) {
                double result = java.lang.Math.pow(numberFieldInput, powerFieldInput);
                resultText.setText(Double.toString(result));
            } else if(event.getSource() == squareRootButton) {
                double result = java.lang.Math.sqrt(numberFieldInput);
                resultText.setText(Double.toString(result));
            }
        } catch(NumberFormatException problem) {
            resultText.setText("Error. Try Again.");
        } 
    }
```

Both powerButton and squareRootButton should be disabled if they are clicked once in any order.

Comment: How is the event handler registered? Can't you use a anonymus class/lambda expression instead? In that case you could use an effectively final local variable in the registering method. Otherwise the only option seems to be to store the data in the nodes themselves (or some other data structure already stored in some field). This would result in code that does not adhere to best practice though...

Comment: The event handler triggers when a button is clicked. There is an user interface that I would show If I could. I haven't learned anything about anonymus class/lambda expression, so I'll just create another instance data variable which would solve my problem but I broke the instructions given. Thanks for responding.

Comment: When do the buttons become re-enabled? Which "instance data fields" do you have access to initially?  Like, if there is an error do the buttons still become disabled? I only ask, because you can bind both buttons disabled property to the same thing.  For example `BooleanBinding buttonDisabledBinding = Bindings.someMethodCalcuatingAgainstResultTextOrinputText` and then bind both buttons disabledProperty to that binding.  No extra field, you just need to work out the Bindings logic.

Comment: Never. Once each button is clicked at least once they're disabled and I didn't know that was possible. Thanks for letting me know.